# Mouse pointer/cursor is missing

Tags: 11.10, mouse

I am looking for help with my mouse every time I turn on my laptop and log into ubuntu 11.10 mouse mouse is not on the screen except when i move my mouse over to the left on the icons there it is i log out and log back in the mouse is on the screen my laptop is a compaq presario v2000

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

At the log in screen, click the gear and select Unity-2d and see if that helps your problem.

Ran across this in my searching: http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/Ubuntu-10-04-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-after-update-td1293320.html

Try posts 4 and 6. You don't have to go into recovery mode for these, but open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and `sudo su`

Comment: tried that went through each one on the list

Comment: That's very odd... Try: `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback` And select "Gnome Classic" on that gear. Also, are you using the touchpad, or an external mouse?

Comment: githlar well that idea did not work but thank you i do not have this file xorg.conf when i searched for it

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't need it in recent versions unless you have a special mouse or something?

Comment: `sudo -s` is widely considered preferable to `sudo su`.